# Want to change the date format from Timestamp to DateTime format

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any equivalent function to convert this kind of SQL timestamp using spark SQL?

> 2022-02-25T09:38:32.000+0000
> want it in yyyyMMddHHmmSS format

*I am using this code but it is not working for me. I am only getting nulls.*

```
val LastUpdate = spark.sql(""" SELECT
(CAST(
    date_format(cc.LastUpdatedDate, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'") as int
 ) )  as LastUpdatedDate
FROM Date_Table cc
""")
```

Comment: if it is stored as string, first convert it to proper timestamp format and then reformat it using `date_format`

Comment: it is in timestamp format from the source.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to proper timestamp format before using `date_format`.

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')

spark.sql('''
    select *, date_format(ts, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') as ts_fmt
    from (
        select *, to_timestamp(ts_str, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") as ts
        from (select '2022-02-25T09:38:32.000+0000' as ts_str))
''').show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------------+-------------------+--------------+
# |ts_str                      |ts                 |ts_fmt        |
# +----------------------------+-------------------+--------------+
# |2022-02-25T09:38:32.000+0000|2022-02-25 09:38:32|20220225093832|
# +----------------------------+-------------------+--------------+
```